# Unit testing Private Functions in Junit with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am Newbie to Java and Junit,

Does Anyone know how to write test cases for private functions in Junit ?

After Some research in Google I setup environment and wrote unit test cases for public functions and mocked parent classes with help of Mock() proxy.

For public function with inline valued arguments, I reached my expectations and tested both Positive and Negative Path.

For Private Methods I followed

[How do I test a private function or a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or][1])

```
Method method = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, argClasses);
method.setAccessible(true);
return method.invoke(targetObject, argObjects);
```

And for fields:

```
Field field = targetClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(object, value);
```

code:

```
public class universalConfiguration { 
   private Integer getTotalDocuments(Client client, String indexName, String indexType, QueryBuilder searchQueryBuilder) {
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch()
             .setIndices(indexName)
             .setTypes(indexType)
             .setSize(0)
             .setQuery(searchQueryBuilder)
             .execute().actionGet();

     return (int) response.getHits().totalHits;
 }
}
```

This is My code I want to test this private method with this public class, i tried to use this method using **getDeclaredMethod** and **setAccessible** but I am getting errors.

```
UniversalConfiguration universalConfiguration = new UniversalConfiguration();    
getTotalDocuments getTotalDocuments= universalConfiguration .
                                         getDeclaredMethod(getTotalDocuments,
                                         client,
                                         indexName,
                                         indexType, 
                                         searchQueryBuilder);           
    getTotalDocuments.setAccessible(true);
```

> getTotalDocuments method cannot be resolved to a type

Correct me If i did any mistakes.

Comment: The best answer in the thread you linked is still in the comments, "Best way to test a private method is not testing it directly".

Comment: please read (and follow) [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 2):

Change your mind about *UnitTests*: A UnitTest does **not** test *code*, it rather tests *behavior*. It does that by using the *public interface* of the unit (which is not necessarily, but usually a `public` method) and verifies the *observable behavior* which is *return values* and or *communication with dependencies*.

`private` methods are *implementation details* that may change for refactoring and this is exactly the time when we want our Unittests *not* to change to guarantee that the desired behavior still exists after the change.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with your code, please change it to below:

```
Class universalConfiguration = UniversalConfiguration.class;    
Class[] cArg = new Class[4];
cArg[0] = Client.class;
cArg[1] = String.class;
cArg[2] = String.class;
cArg[3] = QueryBuilder.class;
Method getTotalDocuments = universalConfiguration.                                          getDeclaredMethod(getTotalDocumentCount,cArg);           
    getTotalDocuments.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: in this line Class[] cArg = new Class[]; 
I am getting error: Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer like this @Aman Chhabra

Comment: getTotalDocumentCount cannot be resolved to a variable this error also coming

Comment: @VijayKrishna Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little opinion biased. However there are two simple ways you can do this:

Test them via a visible method.
Change the visibility to default.

Default visibility will enable the methods to be seen/called at a package level (the method is no longer private) this is a very effective methodology, however your method is no longer private.

Testing via another visible method will enable you to get effective test coverage, although the test could be a little less specific.

How best to approach this will heavily depend on the code you are testing.

Comment: This is not a bad answer, and has been downvoted (I believe) because it offers no specific technical guidance.  In fact, the difficult part of this problem is not the technical part - you can just change private to public and you've solved that part.  So, this answer addresses (or partially addresses) the *hard* part of the problem.  Thanks!